# How to convert a CSV’s timestamp format?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, csv

I am trying to convert a CSV file that returns the time stamp as `hh:mm:s.mmm` into `hhmmssmmm` with the added s for second.

For example I pulled a CSV file in which the time came back as `10:15:7.123` but I want to convert it into `101507123`. Any ideas as to how to do this in Excel?

I don’t want to reach out to our programmers unless I absolutely cannot find the answer here first.

Comment: You could import the CSV, then change the format of the cells in the column.

Comment: Careful though during the import into Excel. Make sure you retain column original data for everything else. For example, if you have a value 00123 and import that column as "General" format, then Excel will drop the leading zeros and you're left with 123. Notoriously common mistake for US zip codes.

Comment: Do you have Excel O365? The new text handling function make this easier.

Comment: Custom cell Formatting?

Answer (score 1):

I have Excel version 2209 and that may make a difference, though it may not if reasonably close.

When I create a CSV file with the example string and import, Excel recognizes it as a time and correctly gets that it is `07` minutes, not some messed up version of that.

So then formatting the column with your string (well, close, as yours gives `101507.Jan` so `hhmmss.000`) gives the desired result.

For this the leading zeros are not a problem anywhere in the string. Even `00:00:01.000` and `00:00:00.001` come through nicely. Excel is noting the delimiting `:` characters in figuring it's a time and how to "populate" the value. So that aspect presents no problems and wouldn't in any version going back quite a ways, not that I've encountered anyway.

Weirdly, it takes a value that clearly includes hours (`10`) and sufficient `:` characters that it is in no doubt that part of it is "15 minutes, 7 second" and then it formats it upon opening as `mm:ss.0` and appends the "am/pm" without it being IT'S own custom formatting string at all. So talk about "makes no sense"...

So basically, just open the CSV with `File|Open` as I did and see if the column is formatted for time. If so, then change the format to what you desire.

To do that automatically, find a way to know the CSV's filename and use VBA to open such, then format its column. You'll need to have a file dedicated to that as the CSV file would not have macros stored in it. Then close the file with the macro and work in the CSV file as desired.

An alternate idea, using a file with a sheet dedicated to this CSV file's end formatting would format a row's cells for the formats the columns in the CSV file will need, then opening the CSV file, selecting al the columns, copying the "template" file's row then pasting the row's formats (only) over the columns in the CSV file so they are all nicely formatted in a single step. Close the file with the formatting "template" and work as you would like in the opened CSV file.